# make cmd put all files in a dir to its own variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make cmd type all files in its own variable.
example:

```
C:\>dir/b
systemlogs.txt
projects.bat

C:\>echo %file1%
systemlogs.txt

C:\>echo %file2%
projects.bat
```

Any tips? Any code i can use?

Comment: The concept behind "each file in its own variable" is called _array_. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "C:\some\folder"

set a=0
for %%f in (*) do (
  set /a a+=1
  set "file!a!=%%~ff"
)

set b=0
for /d %%d in (*) do (
  set /a b+=1
  set "folder!b!=%%~fd"
)

for /l %%i in (1,1,%a%) do echo %%i: !file%%i!
for /l %%i in (1,1,%b%) do echo %%i: !folder%%i!

endlocal
```

Comment: You don't need the `call` in `call set file!a!=%%~ff`  in case of delayed expansion.

Comment: Can you please tell me how i only get the file names and not the full path and file name

Comment: Replace `%%~ff` with `%%~nxf`.

Comment: how do i add the folders?

Comment: Do you want the folder names in `file##` variables as well, or do you want a separate set of variables (e.g. `folder##`)?

Comment: The folder variables will be: folder##

Comment: Then simply run a second loop for folders. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=0
for %%i in (systemlogs.txt projects.bat) do (
    set /a counter+=1
    set "file!counter!=%%i"
)
set "file"
```

..output is:

```
file1=systemlogs.txt
file2=projects.bat
```